# SQL Counting rows together

Tags: php, mysql

```
id  partner_id  date_created    status  item_id
3   2   1322861013  redirected  1
4   2   1322943245  redirected  6
5   3   1322943246  redirected  6
6   2   1322943247  redirected  6
```

How do i count how many rows with the same item_id that exists? The table name is `orders`

Example for the above i wish it to output:

```
There's 3 rows with the item_id 6
There's 1 rows with the item_id 1
```

I only know how to do this little more complicated with some php loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT item_id, COUNT(id) FROM orders 
GROUP BY item_id
```

Answer (score 2):

The pattern to use here is `COUNT()` combined with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT item_id, COUNT(id) AS item_count FROM orders GROUP BY item_id
```

You will get back two columns that can be easily reformatted as required.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql> create table test(
    ->        row integer
    -> ) ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> insert into test values ( 3 ) , ( 3 ) , ( 3 ) , ( 1 ) ;
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select count(*) from test group by row;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        1 |
|        3 |
+----------+
2 rows in set (0.03 sec)

mysql>
```